# Uploading apps to the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: application-submission

I have created an application in Visual Studio 2010 and i would like to publish it in the Ubuntu Software Center. Will I able to do that?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Will that game work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8):

As a free/open source app, you essentially have two options:

- submit it as [a .snap package](http://snapcraft.io/create/) for Ubuntu Core and Ubuntu Desktop
- publish [in a PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find a lot of information on http://developer.ubuntu.com/. Good luck, [ncsreeram](https://askubuntu.com/users/104614/ncsreeram)!

Answer (score 0):

This is THE place :-)

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/new/

but is being updated. See this page

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppDevUploadProcess

I consider the best option now (2013-06-11) not to submit.

To share my experience, I submitted an app a minute ago and receive the notification that the app will not be published until the new 'Ubuntu Software Center' is ready.

Good luck.